# How Set a Price According to Quantity and Size of the Product?

Tags: php, magento, product

I m new to magento i have just try to configurable product with quantity and size attribute
For example

```
Size = 2*2 and 3*3 and Qauntity=100,200,300
```

I want to set the price according to Size and Quantity
For Examole if Size 2*2 and Quantity=100 then Price=1000
and if Size 2*2 and Quantity=200 then Price=1500

So, how can i do these ?

Comment: What did you try so far getting your results? any error? any code?

Comment: i only try to create configurable product and attribute with size nd quantity but it not working properly like if i select 2*2 nd 100 its fine but if i try to select 3*3 and 100 so its not work properly..